# ExpoKit: "Native Module cannot be null" error after installing expo-in-app-purchase

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoa, npm, expo

I'm currently running an Expo app that was recently ejected to ExpoKit. It has been working as expected up until I installed `expo-in-app-purchases` from https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases like so:

```
npm i expo-in-app-purchases
cd ios
pod install
```

I then import the module in one of my app files like so:

```
import * as InAppPurchases from 'expo-in-app-purchases';
```

When I try to run the app on the Expo client, I get the following error:
[image: Error message]

And When I try to build the app on XCode, I get the following build error:
[image: "Use of undeclared identifier"]

I tried linking the package using `react-native link` but it did not fix the issue.
I also tried removing `node_modules` and re-installing them along with `pod update && pod install`, but the issue persists.

Any help is appreciated!

Here are `package.json` dependencies:

```
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "^5.0.1",
    "expo-font": "^5.0.1",
    "expo-in-app-purchases": "^6.0.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^5.0.1",
    "expokit": "^33.0.4",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1"
```

Comment: Looks like some linking issue. Have you exported to expo kit? That might be one of  the issue.

Comment: @RishavKumar I have already exported to ExpoKit. It has been working fine until now

Comment: The `SK…` constants come from [Apple's `StoreKit` framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit?language=objc). Could you ensure that `EXInAppPurchasesModule.h` is also available in your project and doesn't render any errors? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

Double check your unimodules configuration.

Try and exclude face detector too. I've had issues with this messing up the build chain on SDK 33.

https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules#configure-ios

Comment: I have followed the configuration instructions but the issue persists.

Comment: im seeing the same issue, did you get it sorted ? i did notice that in the Xcode workspace project, there was NO header file for ```EXInAppPurchasesModule.h``` even though ```npm install expo-in-app-purchases``` ran OK, as did ```pod install```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I spent way too much time on this. Solution is to **remove** expo-in-app-purchases from **podfile -> exclude: [...]** and do `pod install` again.

[image]